# How to generate jhipster rest end point

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jhipster, auto-generate

How to generate with console command (like yo jhipster:entity  --[options]) just REST endPoint with DTO and empty service without entity ?
my service will be use another and point for getting data and just transform data to another DTO and I want to generate only stub endpoints with tests by command

Comment: It's not possible, the options can be seen with `yo jhipster:entity --help`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do that but you can check all the options that jhipster entity offers here: https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/